# Соединить результаты запроса, не используя UNION

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть запрос:

```sql
SELECT TOP (20)
    ValueTable.Id id,
    ValueTable.RecordTime recordtime,
    NamesTable.FullName fullname

FROM 
    DB.ValueTable ValueTable
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT ID, FullName
        FROM FullNamesTable1

        UNION ALL

        SELECT ID, FullName
        FROM FullNamesTable2
    ) NamesTable
    ON ValueTable.ID = NamesTable.ID

WHERE
    id > 8000

ORDER BY recordtime DESC
```

Проблема в том, что тот sql, который используется на сервере, очень старый/странный, и он не умеет использовать `UNION` внутри подзапроса.

То есть, запрос

```sql
SELECT ID, FullName
FROM FullNamesTable1

UNION ALL

SELECT ID, FullName
FROM FullNamesTable2
```

вполне рабочий, и выдаст значения, но внутри оператора `FROM` он уже не умеет понимать данный оператор. Как можно конкатинировать две одинаковые таблицы иным способом? `WITH` и `#TempTable` не помогут по той же причине отсталости sql.

UPDATE:

Запрос без `UNION` тоже полностью рабочий:

```sql
SELECT TOP (20)
    ValueTable.Id id,
    ValueTable.RecordTime recordtime,
    NamesTable.FullName fullname

FROM 
    DB.ValueTable ValueTable
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT ID, FullName
        FROM FullNamesTable1
    ) NamesTable
    ON ValueTable.ID = NamesTable.ID

WHERE
    id > 8000

ORDER BY recordtime DESC
```

Версию sql я не могу узнать, знаю лишь то, что это сервер со SCADA. В других подобных запросах проблема решалась таким образом, что все `UNION` выносились наверх, но, мне кажется, это не самое правильное решение:

```sql
(
    SELECT TOP (20)
        ValueTable.Id id,
        ValueTable.RecordTime recordtime,
        NamesTable.FullName fullname

    FROM 
        DB.ValueTable ValueTable
    JOIN
        FullNamesTable1 NamesTable
        ON ValueTable.ID = NamesTable.ID

    WHERE
        id > 8000

    ORDER BY recordtime DESC

) UNION All (

    SELECT TOP (20)
        ValueTable.Id id,
        ValueTable.RecordTime recordtime,
        NamesTable.FullName fullname

    FROM 
        DB.ValueTable ValueTable
    JOIN
        FullNamesTable2 NamesTable
        ON ValueTable.ID = NamesTable.ID

    WHERE
        id > 8000

    ORDER BY recordtime DESC
)
```

Comment: Укажите точную версию сервера, без этого на такой вопрос ответить невозможно.

Comment: Не из-за этого не работает: WHERE    id > 8000? 
Алиас здесь не может использоваться. Нужно указать таблицу.

Comment: Ничто не мешает JOIN отдельных таблиц, и потом уже UNION.

Comment: `SELECT TOP (20) ...` - это явно не про MySQL. Выясните, какой именно у Вас сервер БД... думаю, это будет SQL Server aka MS SQL.

Comment: Если TOP() работает со скобками, то версия не такая уж и старая. :-)

Comment: @Akina немного дополнил вопрос. Это не совсем бд, это скада-сервер, который в том числе имеет внутри себя субд. Но и сами скада-разработчики, которые настраивали систему, не могут ответить, какое подмножество sql здесь используется. Опытным путём прошлые программисты выяснили, что это наиболее похоже на старый MySQL, но точно неизвестно. А про отдельные join -  сейчас так и используем, но, как мне кажется, это костыль, а не нормальное решение, поэтому и зажал вопрос.

Comment: *мне кажется, это не самое правильное решение:* Вполне себе решение. Только сортировку надо вынести из подзапросов наружу. А из отобранных записей отбирать первые 20 уже на уровне клиента.